# AWS: How to make private API Gateways testable for developers (on their clients)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have created a **private** API gateway that uses Lambda functions in a VPC. It should deliberately not be a public API gateway, as the endpoints should only be exposed within the AWS account.

However, this is now causing problems for my colleague who is developing the Python Lambdas. It is understandable that he wants to run his tests (Postman, pytest) on his client. However, there is no VPN, DX, etc. to this AWS account.

What solutions/architecture patterns exist for this case? I fully understand that this can't currently work this way. But what would be a way to allow certain people this type of access, (if possible) without making the API gateway public? If necessary, one could use other resources or other configurations for the development environment - however, the closer DEV is to PROD, the better, of course. Thanks for all ideas.

Comment: You already answered your own question: VPN, DX or ssh tunnel through some bastion host in a public subnet.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a Cloud9 instance as a development environment. This is a IDE-cloud based service to serve your use case.

https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/aws-cloud9-ide/

**To keep your environment safe, you can create that instance without any remote ingress rule**. The only way that your colleagues can access is over his web browser from AWS Console.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/ec2-ssm.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/create-environment-main.html#create-environment-console

From there, your colleagues can leverage any development tools and can call directly to your internal API Gateway which is accessible over VPC Endpoint. Also, please remember to whitelist the Endpoint's security group to allow Cloud9 instance.